# extract paragraph from text saved on CLOB

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract a whole paragraph from CLOB which I converted into String, the problem with regex I'm wrote

the Paragraph is start with ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS but the problem is this statement could have multiple white spaces, blank lines, or text and might ends with white spaces, blank lines,  text , line of *****, or line of #####.

examples: like below:

1.
/*********SOME BLANK LINES*****/

ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS: some text.........some text......................
..........some text.

2.
/*********SOME BLANK LINES*****/

ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:

/*********SOME BLANK LINES*****/

some text.........some text......................
..........some text

3.
/*********SOME BLANK LINES*****/

ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:

/*********SOME BLANK LINES*****/

some text.........some text......................
..........some text.

some text.......

---

4.
/#######SOME TEXT###############/

ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:

/*********SOME BLANK LINES*****/
some text.........some text......................
..........some text.

some text.......

line of (*)****************-

here what I tried so far:
    public static String getSentence(String text, String word) {

```
       final String lcword = word.toLowerCase();

       return END_OF_SENTENCE.splitAsStream(text)

               .filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(lcword))

               .findAny()

               .orElse(null);

   }



   private static String processUpdateCmpln(String text) throws IOException{

          //String lines = we.getText();

                 String ResultString = null;

                 Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\.*ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:\\s+(.*)[\\n*]$", Pattern.DOTALL);

                 Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(text);

                 if (regexMatcher.find()) {

                     ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);

                 } 

                        return ResultString;





   }

   //3609601

   private static String processUpdateCmplns(String text) throws IOException{

          //^.*\b(ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:)\b.*$

          Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:\\s*(.*?)((?:\r?\n+|\r){2,}|$)");





   Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

   String ResultString = null;

   while (m.find()) {

          ResultString=m.group(1);

   }
```

EDIT:

a real example as below:

I need to extract the text from ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS: to ERP 18MAR2016, Please note ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS: may appear more than once

18-Mar-2016 12:50 (GMT-4:00) added by lolo :

REQUEST#:    98765432

RELATED CASE TR(S) IF APPLICABLE:  none

REASON FOR INTERACTION:  Some text..

IF POTENTIAL PRIORITY PC = YES (INDICATE WHY):  no

HAS THE PRODUCT WITH THE PROBLEM BEEN USED:  yes

PRODUCT REPLACEMENT REQUESTED (YES/NO, SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT):  no

ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:

Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..

ERP 18MAR2016

---

17-Mar-2016 12:30 (GMT-4:00) added by John:

FOLLOW UP TEMPLATE

REQUEST#:  1234567

RELATED CASE TR(S) IF APPLICABLE: Not applicable

REASON FOR INTERACTION: SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT

IF POTENTIAL PRIORITY PC = YES (INDICATE WHY): See original request

HAS THE PRODUCT WITH THE PROBLEM BEEN USED: See original request

PRODUCT REPLACEMENT REQUESTED (YES/NO, SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT): See original request

ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:

Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..

Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..

RLH   17MAR2016

Comment: Try `String pat = "(?sm)^ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:(?:(?!^ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:).)*";`, see https://regex101.com/r/pH8yK8/1

Comment: Or a similar unrolled one [`String pat = "(?m)^ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:(.*(?:\r?\n(?!ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:).*)*)";`](https://regex101.com/r/pH8yK8/3)

Comment: Is `ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS` at the beginning of the line? If not, you need to add `\s*` to the patterns above after the `^`.

Comment: please confirm the text I tested against is the text you have, or else, please provide an updated regex fiddle.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  
Thank you very much!! it works fine, but can you include this case as well: to extract until first all in CAPS word reached?

Comment: Untill 1 uppercase? It would be `[^A-Z]*`. If two: `(?:(?![A-Z]{2}).)*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you again so the regex will be: "(?m)^\\s*+ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:(.*+(?:\r?\n\\s*+(?!ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:).*+)*(?:(?![A-Z]{2}).)*),.....and may you please write another one which extract from ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS: until the first word in CAPS (e.g MED)

Comment: Something like [`String pat = "(?s)ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:((?:(?!ERP 18MAR2016).)*)ERP 18MAR2016";`](https://regex101.com/r/sA9uI3/1)?

Comment: Or maybe [`ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:((?:(?!\b[A-Z]{3}\b).)*)\b[A-Z]{3}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/sA9uI3/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works perfectly fine on non Java environment, but it does not work on Java. any explanation?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need the following:

```
String val = "18-Mar-2016 12:50 (GMT-4:00) added by lolo :\n\nREQUEST#: 98765432\n\nRELATED CASE TR(S) IF APPLICABLE: none\n\nREASON FOR INTERACTION: Some text..\n\nIF POTENTIAL PRIORITY PC = YES (INDICATE WHY): no\n\nHAS THE PRODUCT WITH THE PROBLEM BEEN USED: yes\n\nPRODUCT REPLACEMENT REQUESTED (YES/NO, SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT): no\n\nADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:\n\nSome text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..\n\nERP 18MAR2016\n\n17-Mar-2016 12:30 (GMT-4:00) added by John:\n\nFOLLOW UP TEMPLATE\n\nREQUEST#: 1234567\n\nRELATED CASE TR(S) IF APPLICABLE: Not applicable\n\nREASON FOR INTERACTION: SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT\n\nIF POTENTIAL PRIORITY PC = YES (INDICATE WHY): See original request\n\nHAS THE PRODUCT WITH THE PROBLEM BEEN USED: See original request\n\nPRODUCT REPLACEMENT REQUESTED (YES/NO, SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT): See original request\n\nADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:\n\nSome text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..\n\nSome text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..\n\nRLH 17MAR2016";
String pat = "(?s)ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:((?:(?!\\b[A-Z]{3}\\b).)*)\\b[A-Z]{3}\\b";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(pat);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(val);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1).trim());
    System.out.println("---- NEXT ------");
}
```

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/osyMSc)

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sA9uI3/2).

Note that you need to use `while (matcher.find())` to get multiple matches.

The pattern matches:

- `ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP DETAILS:` - a literal string
- `((?:(?!\b[A-Z]{3}\b).)*)` - Group 1 (`matcher.group(1)`) capturing any character that is not a starting point of a 3 uppercase letter sequence that is a whole word
- `\b[A-Z]{3}\b` - a leading word boundary + 3 uppercase ASCII letters + a trailing word boundary (a whole 3-uppercase letter word)

Comment: I updated the answer with the `(?:(?![A-Z]{2}).)*` bit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience but i have updated the question with real example, the regex you have provided did not work as expected as it fails in the example i just provided.